# Saving output file created a specific row and cell from Table in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to take a string from a specific row and cell from the table in my word document and have it automatically saved as my output filename. So for example, Row 1 Cell 1 has the name "Samuel". So I want to take that name and have it become the filename in the output file I created. So in my code, I have already created a way to create output 2 files based on a previous if condition. Now its just a matter of the file being saved automatically as the location I specified for it. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub GenerateButton_Click()
Dim CellText As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 4

CellText = ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Text
CellText = TrimCellText(CellText)

If CellText = "Module name" Then
            Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
            Dim ood As New FileSystemObject
            Dim filestream As TextStream
            Set filestream = fso.CreateTextFile("filepath", True)
            Set filestream = ood.CreateTextFile("filepath", True)
End If
Next
End Sub

Function TrimCellText(sCellText) As String
    Dim sLastChar As String

    sLastChar = Right(sCellText, 1)
    Do While sLastChar = Chr(7) Or sLastChar = Chr(13)
        sCellText = Left(sCellText, Len(sCellText) - 1)
        sLastChar = Right(sCellText, 1)
    Loop
    TrimCellText = sCellText
End Function
```

Comment: And how is the code not working? You don't ask a question.

Comment: This code works. but it will only set the output filename to whatever i type in the filepath. for example: "C:\MyDocuments\hi.txt". Instead, I need it to grab the string that is next too the string I found in ym first "If" condition which is "Module name". So It would grab the string in row 1 cell 2 which is next too Module name

Answer (score 0):

You're only ever looking at the content in the first cell, but the data you want to retrieve are in the cell next to it. Try:

```
Private Sub GenerateButton_Click()
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim filestream As TextStream
Dim CellText As String
Dim i As Long

With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 To 4
    If Split(.Tables(i).Cells(1, 1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "Module name" Then
      CellText = Split(.Tables(i).Cells(1, 2).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
      Set filestream = fso.CreateTextFile(CellText, True)
    End If
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** I've omitted 'Dim ood As New FileSystemObject' and 'Set filestream = ood.CreateTextFile("filepath", True)' as they seem redundant. I've also relocated 'Dim fso As New FileSystemObject' and 'Dim filestream As TextStream' as I doubt you need to recreate these on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hey @macropod Thank you so much for answering. I need it to create to output files. In my original code, it did that based on if the "if" condition is true or not. And i set them to the directory path I wanted. how do I set the directory path? And will it create 2 output files?

Comment: Your original code creates two copies of the same file - and only if the condition is True, and that is what my code replicates (but only for generating a single output file). In any event, You don't need fso for this; all you need is Word's own Save As function.